# Javascript Custom Library

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out why the following is not working:

My custom JS library

```
(function ($, undefined) {

var expenses = expenses || {};

expenses.report = function () {

    var deleteReport = function () {
        alert('test');
    };

    return {
        deleteReport: deleteReport
    };
};

window.expenses = expenses;

})(jQuery);
```

How I am calling it on the page:

```
$(function() { expenses.report.deleteReport() };
```

The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {



        var deleteReport = function () {

            alert('test');

        };



        return {

            deleteReport: deleteReport

        };

    } has no method 'deleteReport'
```

I'm still familiarizing myself with javascript and jquery so I'm sure there is something simple in the design that I am leaving out. I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Wow, this is Javascript run amok, way more obscure than needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
expenses.report
```

is a function.

```
expenses.report()
```

is the return value of that function, which is the object you defined here:

```
{
    deleteReport: deleteReport
};
```

So if you want to call deleteReport, you need to go like this:

```
expenses.report().deleteReport()
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `expenses.report` is a function, which returns an object with a `deleteReport` method:

```
expenses.report().deleteReport();
```

If you instead wanted `expenses.report.deleteReport()`, you have a few options:

1) Change the function to auto-execute and return the object right away.

```
expenses.report = (function () {
    var deleteReport = function () {
        alert('test');
    };

    return {
        deleteReport: deleteReport
    };
})();
```

2) Set the object and function directly if you don't really need the closure or `deleteReport` as a separate variable.

```
expenses.report = {
    deleteReport: function () {
        alert('test');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`expenses.report`  is a function that returns an object when executed.  Since it is never executed, the object containing deleteReport does not exist.  I would make your `expenses.report` function self invoking, ie:

```
expenses.report = (function () {

    var deleteReport = function () {
        alert('test');
    };

    return {
        deleteReport: deleteReport
    };
})();
```

now you will be able to call `expenses.report.deleteReport()`